# SonarQube - Is there basic example/explanation of how coverage issues can be resolved?

Tags: python, django, testing, sonarqube

I'm very new to using SonarQube/Cloud (so please be gentle!) and am trying to work out how to improve the '0% coverage on new code' that my code has.

Here's an example:

I added the code:

```
    validation_errors = []

    for field in required:
        if field not in request.POST:
            validation_errors.append("field '{0}' missing".format(field))

    if len(validation_errors) > 0:
        return JsonResponse({'errors': validation_errors}, status=400 )
```

and I have a (Django) test for this:

```
def test_required_params(self):
        # no username
        response = self.client.post(self.url, { 'password': 'secret', 'media_file': self.video_file })
        self.assertRaises(forms.ValidationError)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 400)
```

But when I run the sonar-scanner, in the online report, I get the message that these lines are not covered (see: https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures?id=django_oppia&metric=new_coverage&selected=django_oppia%3Aapi%2Fmedia.py)

I'm sure I must have some very basic mis/non-understanding of what the coverage metric actually means.

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain to me what I need to add/update in my code (just the specific example above), so the SonarCloud analysis doesn't continue to flag this as not covered.

Thanks for your help - if you need any extra info on code/platform/versions etc, just let me know.

**Edit**
The sonar-scanner command that I'm running:

```
sonar-scanner \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=django_oppia \
  -Dsonar.organization=alexlittle-github \
  -Dsonar.sources=. \
  -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io \
  -Dsonar.login=xxxxxxxxxx \
  -Dsonar.exclusions=docs/_build/**/*
```

I run this from the root of my source code, and I haven't specified/edited anything in the sonar/conf/sonar-scanner.properties file (it's just the default installed version)

Comment: where did you add the validation code? Are you calling `form.is_valid()` somewhere to actually run the validation when the form is submitted? Also, `self.assertRaises(forms.ValidationError)` doesn't do anything because you're not calling a function. Wrap your `self.client.post()` call in a `with self.assertRaises(forms.ValidationError):`

Comment: oh but your code isn't raising an exception when validation fails, so `assertRaises(ValidationError)` isn't the right test. You just want to check the response has status 400 and contains the errors.

Comment: but i don't know why sonarqube says you code isn't covered because it obviously is. Do you have to tell it which tests to run? sorry, don't know much about sonarqube (note: you gave us viewing access to your entire source code, not sure that's the intention)

Comment: Can you please post your sonar-project.properties or the sonar params being passed to sonar-scanner. I usually find if its a dead 0% its a misconfiguration of the coverage report. i.e. not sending it to sonar or not producing it.

Comment: @metalisticpain - have just added the command I'm running as an edit to the post, with the params

Comment: @dirkgroten - viewing the whole source code is no problem, as it's an open source project on GitHub

Comment: @dirkgroten - the specific piece of code that I gave isn't calling form.is_valid(), it's an API for allowing file uploads, so I should get this updated, so maybe wasn't the best example for me to give. But in any case, the scan doesn't seem to find any of the tests I've added. I'm not specifically directing sonar-scanner to tests, they're set up in the 'normal' Django way, but maybe this isn't enough.

Comment: Perhaps in addition to those properties set `-Dsonar.python.coverage.reportPath=path_to_coverage`, See https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Python+Coverage+Results+Import

Comment: @metalisticpain - thanks I'll take a look at this and let you know how I get on

Comment: @metalisticpain - generating the coverage report and then adding this to the properties was the solution, so if you could add your comment as an answer, I'll mark as accepted. The coverage is only 1.6%, but I only ran the coverage on one package, but at least it's non-0 so heading in the right direction now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments post above by @metalisticpain, I've now got this working.
The issue was due to me missing out creating the coverage report.

For anyone else having the same issue, here's how I resolved it...

First I ran the coverage tool (from the root of my project directory):

```
coverage erase
coverage run --branch --source=oppia
coverage xml -i
```

Then pointed the sonar-scanner to this coverage.xml file:

```
sonar-scanner \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=django_oppia \
  -Dsonar.organization=alexlittle-github \
  -Dsonar.sources=. \
  -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io \
  -Dsonar.login=xxxxxxxxxx \
  -Dsonar.exclusions=docs/_build/**/*,tests/**/*,oppiamobile/settings_secret.py \
  -Dsonar.python.coverage.reportPath=./coverage.xml
```

I added some extra exclusions, but what actually made the difference was adding the reportPaths to the coverage.xml

Comment: "Property 'sonar.python.coverage.reportPath' has been removed. Please use 'sonar.python.coverage.reportPaths' instead." ~ SonarQube 8.2 maybe earlier.